# Access local functions in one angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs and javascript. I have a working code like this:

**my_ctrl.js**

```
app.controller('my_ctrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
    $scope.getmymodel = function(){$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/getmymodel',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function(response){$scope.getmymodel=response.data;});};
    $scope.getmymodel();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="my_ctrl as ctrl" ng-cloak>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="model in getmymodel">
            <td>{{model.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I wanted to call the js function using controller in HTML and make the function call local to the controller. I modified the code as below but have no luck. Any help is appreciated!

**my_ctrl.js**

```
app.controller('my_ctrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
    this.getmymodel = function(){$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/getmymodel',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function(response){this.getmymodel=response.data;});};
    this.getmymodel();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="my_ctrl as ctrl" ng-cloak>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="model in ctrl.getmymodel">
            <td>{{model.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign this to variable like

```
var vm = this;
```

in controller

and define function like

```
vm.getmymodel = function(){};
```

and in HTML

```
<div ng-controller="my_ctrl as vm">
   ...
   and call function 

   <tr ng-repeat="model in vm.getmymodel">
      <td>{{model.name}}</td>
   </tr>

   ...
</div>
```